# Visual Studio Code - Plain text - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I tried various methods on here and google, but I can't get my JavaScript file to format the [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion#IntelliSense) correctly. Below are screenshots of the problem I have.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqUqT.png)

[Correctly formatted color text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJK47.png)

Comment: syntax highlighting for JavaScript and CSS are done by different TextMate files and the theme, find out if there is a different TextMate scope for the stuff you think is incorrect colored, all the white stuff are variables and most likely have the same scope

Answer (score -1):

You probably meant to type `ampmEl.innerText = ampm`

Comment: I appreciate the comment. That's not the problem that I'm having. If you can see the rest of the code is plain white text. It's not color coding correctly with the file and also not formatting like my CSS and html files

Comment: Syntax highlighting sometimes breaks when there is invalid code written. After changing line 20 try restarting your IDE. Also where do you even call that function?

Answer (score -1):

The color theme and theme [was the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328016/vs-code-plain-text-javascript/73328128#comment129497689_73328016).

Answer for this problem is [rioV8's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328016/vs-code-plain-text-javascript/73328128#comment129497689_73328016):

> Syntax highlighting for JavaScript and CSS are done by different [TextMate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate) files and the theme. Find out if there is a different TextMate scope for the stuff you think is incorrect colored. All the white stuff are variables and most likely have the same scope.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."* (it covers answers as well)). Please ***never ever do this again***. Thanks in advance.